# Реализация шаблонного класса с разделением на .h и .cpp - файлы

Tags: c++

Попытался реализовать просто шаблонный класс с разделением на .h и .cpp - файлы:

my_class.h:

```
template<class my_type>

class my_class
{

public:

    my_class()
    {
    
    }


    int method_1(my_type my_type_);

};
```

my_class.cpp:

```
#include "my_class.h"

template<class my_type>
int my_class<my_type>::method_1(my_type my_type_)
{
    std::cout << "method_1:" << my_type_ << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

main:

```
#include "my_class.h"

int main()
{

    my_class<std::string> my_class_;

    std::string my_string = "hello";

    my_class_.method_1(my_string);

}
```

Но компилятор указывает на "неразрешенный символ" - ни как не могу понять, где он не разрешенный символ то прячется ?

Comment: Ну вот поставьте себя на место компилятора — откуда ему знать, компилируя my_class.cpp, для какого типа `my_type` генерировать код? Вот он его и не генерирует... А при линковке его и не хватает. Словом, не пытайтесь открывать Америку через форточку, используйте шаблоны, как это положено - в заголовочных файлах...

Comment: @Harry, да я так и использовал. Но каждый раз подключая заголовочный файл - я разве не дублирую этот код во всех подключаемых файлах, тем самым раздувая скомпилированный файл ?

Comment: Встречный вопрос: включая каждый раз `<vector>`, например, вы дублируете код во всех файлах, раздувая скомпилированный файл? :) Не волнуйтесь, это указание, **как** сгенерировать код, а уж скомпилируется он только когда надо и не больше, чем надо :)